# AngularJS function calls using arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, callback, nested-function

This AngularJS function isn't working quite the way I would expect it to:

```
app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', 'ForTHEOrder', function($scope, commence) { 
  commence.success(function(boolean) { 
    $scope.rabbitCat = boolean; 
    $scope.clownFox = boolean; 
    $scope.mongolFaun = boolean; 
    $scope.deerWolf = boolean; 
    $scope.stoatFire = boolean; 
    $scope.bearDragon = boolean; 
    $scope.deadWeasel = boolean; 
    $scope.n_nUrsulafox = boolean; 
  }); 
  commence.failure(function(boolean) { 
    $scope.rabbitCat = boolean; 
    $scope.clownFox = boolean; 
    $scope.mongolFaun = boolean; 
    $scope.deerWolf = boolean; 
    $scope.stoatFire = boolean; 
    $scope.bearDragon = boolean; 
    $scope.deadWeasel = boolean; 
    $scope.n_nUrsulafox = boolean; 
  }); 
}]);
```

It should be passing an array into the function call, containing a set of objects, which are then utilised by the nested function call. However, that doesn't seem to be what's actually happening and when I try to run the code I get an error. I can post the HTML if need be, but what interests me is the action of the array. Does anyone have suggestions as to what the array is doing here?

I am currently getting the following error message:

```
Error: $scope.success is not a function
@http://www.orderofthemouse.co.uk/js/controllers/MainController.js:102:3
e@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.5/angular.min.js:36:338
Ce/this.$get</</<@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.5/angular.min.js:75:387
H/<@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.5/angular.min.js:59:19
r@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.5/angular.min.js:7:406
H@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.5/angular.min.js:59:2
g@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.5/angular.min.js:51:299
g@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.5/angular.min.js:51:316
C/<@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.5/angular.min.js:50:414
rc/d/</<@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.5/angular.min.js:17:477
Me/this.$get</k.prototype.$eval@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.5/angular.min.js:125:116
Me/this.$get</k.prototype.$apply@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.5/angular.min.js:125:330
rc/d/<@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.5/angular.min.js:17:435
e@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.5/angular.min.js:36:338
rc/d@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.5/angular.min.js:17:356
rc@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.5/angular.min.js:18:151
Gd@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.5/angular.min.js:16:463
@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.5/angular.min.js:249:238
a@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.5/angular.min.js:164:4
gf/c@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.5/angular.min.js:32:280
```

The HTML code requested is as follows:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>The Order of the Mouse</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/jpg" href="./ico/favicon.jpg">
    <meta name="description" content="Psychological horror/detective/spiritual RPG set the medieval, magical future world of 2079; Web-Based">
    <meta name="keywords" content="RPG, Horror, Detective, Order of the Mouse, Rabbit-Cat, Dragon-Bear, Clown-Fox, Deer-Wolf">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
    <script src="./vendor/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./vendor/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./vendor/underscore.js"></script>
    <script src="./vendor/backbone.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./vendor/backbone.marionette.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./react/build/react.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./react/build/react-dom.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://www.wavepot.com/build.js"></script>
    <script src="http://www.wavepot.com/app.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:500,300,700,200' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  </head>
  <body ng-app="myApp">
    <div class="header">
      <div class="container">
        <h1></h1>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="main" ng-controller="MainController">
      <div class="container">

        <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
         <h2>{{ placeholder }}</h2>

        <div ng-repeat="character in characters" class="col-md-6"> 
                <div class="thumbnail"> 
                    <img ng-src="{{  }}"> 
                    <p class="name">{{ character.name }}</p> 
                    <p class="name">{{ character.age }}</p>
                    <p class="url"><a href="http://orderofthemouse.co.uk/">{{ character.url }}</p></a>
                    <p class="coolness">{{ success.rabbitCat }}</p> 
                    <p class="warmness">{{ failure.rabbitCat }}</p> 
                    <div class="HP">
                        <p class="Up" ng-click="plusOne($index)"> {{  }} </p>
                        <p class="Down" ng-click="minusOne($index)"> {{ }} </p>
                    </div>
                </div> 
                </div>

      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="footer">
      <div class="container">
        <h2></h2>
        <img style="display: none" src="" width="" />
      </div>
    </div>

    <script>
    import sin from '<redacted>'; 
    import { noise } from '<redacted>';

    export function dsp(t) {
    return (sin(t, 440) + noise()) * 0.1;
    }
    </script>

    <audio controls autoplay>
       <source src="DozyOuija.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
       <source src="DozyOuija.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
       <p>Your User Agent does not support the HTML5 Audio element.</p>
    </audio> 



    <!-- Modules -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>

    <!-- Controllers -->
    <script src="js/controllers/MainController.js"></script>
    <script>
<!-- Analytics -->
<!-- ANALYTICS REDACTED -->
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Let me know if anyone needs further details to help them get to the bottom of the problem.

Comment: *"I get an error"*. Do you think the error can be of any interest?

Comment: It outputs an error saying the array of $scope is undefined then shows {{ rabbitCat.boolean }} instead of displaying the boolean.

Comment: Now displaying a slightly different error. Amended info to reflect.

Comment: The error message isn't of much use without the full source code (so that the program can actually be run).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', 'ForTHEOrder', function($scope, commence) { 
  commence.success(function(boolean) { 
    $scope.rabbitCat = boolean; 
    $scope.clownFox = boolean; 
    $scope.mongolFaun = boolean; 
    $scope.deerWolf = boolean; 
    $scope.stoatFire = boolean; 
    $scope.bearDragon = boolean; 
    $scope.deadWeasel = boolean; 
    $scope.n_nUrsulafox = boolean; 
$scope.$apply();
  }); 
  commence.failure(function(boolean) { 
    $scope.rabbitCat = boolean; 
    $scope.clownFox = boolean; 
    $scope.mongolFaun = boolean; 
    $scope.deerWolf = boolean; 
    $scope.stoatFire = boolean; 
    $scope.bearDragon = boolean; 
    $scope.deadWeasel = boolean; 
    $scope.n_nUrsulafox = boolean; 
$scope.$apply();
  }); 
}]);
```

Comment: Thanks. It has at least progressed things somewhat. Still getting an error, though :/.

Comment: Added. Let me know if you need anything else.